# Atualizando Listview quando volto de uma tela

Tags: android, listview

Tenho uma ListView que tem um botão que vai pra outra tela que ao preencher essa tela e clicar no botão salvar, ele retorna a ListView porém não encontrei um modo de atualizar essa ListView.

Segue os códigos:

ListActivity

```
public class ListReceitaActivity extends ActionBarActivity {

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_list_receita);



    refreshLista();


}

public void refreshLista(){
    ReceitaDAO receita = new ReceitaDAO(this);
    List<Receita> list = receita.getLista();
    ListView listView = (ListView) findViewById(android.R.id.list);
    listView.setAdapter(new ReceitaAdapter(this, list, listView));
}



@Override
public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
    // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
    getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.menu_list_receita, menu);
    return true;
}

@Override
public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
    switch (item.getItemId()){
        case android.R.id.home:
            NavUtils.navigateUpFromSameTask(this);
            return true;
        case R.id.action_add_despesa:
            Intent intent = new Intent(this, EditaReceitaActivity.class);
            startActivity(intent);
            return true;
    }

    return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
}
}
```

Adapter

```
public class ReceitaAdapter extends BaseAdapter {
private Context context;
List<Receita> lista;
private ListView listView;

NumberFormat nf = NumberFormat.getCurrencyInstance();

public ReceitaAdapter(Context context, List<Receita> lista, ListView listView) {
    this.context = context;
    this.lista = lista;
    this.listView = listView;
}




@Override
public int getCount() {
    return lista.size();
}

@Override
public Object getItem(int position) {
    return lista.get(position);
}

@Override
public long getItemId(int i) {
    return i;
}

@Override
public View getView(int position, View view, ViewGroup viewGroup) {
    final int auxPosition = position;
    LayoutInflater inflater = (LayoutInflater)
            context.getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);

    final RelativeLayout layout = (RelativeLayout)
            inflater.inflate(R.layout.row, null);

    listView.setDivider(null);


    listView.setOnItemClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> adapterView, View view, int i, long l) {
            Intent intent = new Intent(context, EditaReceitaActivity.class);
            int position = (int) l;
            Receita receita = (Receita) getItem(position);
            intent.putExtra("id", receita.getId());

            context.startActivity(intent);
        }
    });


    listView.setOnItemLongClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemLongClickListener() {
        @Override
        public boolean onItemLongClick(AdapterView<?> adapterView, View view, int i, final long l) {
            AlertDialog.Builder alert = new AlertDialog.Builder(context);

            final CharSequence[] opcoes = {"Editar", "Apagar"};

            alert.setTitle("Escolha a opção");
            alert.setItems(opcoes, new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                @Override
                public void onClick(DialogInterface dialogInterface, int item) {
                    switch (item) {
                        case 0:
                            Intent intent = new Intent(context, EditaReceitaActivity.class);
                            int position = (int) l;
                            Receita receita = (Receita) getItem(position);
                            intent.putExtra("id", receita.getId());

                            context.startActivity(intent);
                            break;
                        case 1:
                            ReceitaDAO receitaDAO = new ReceitaDAO(context);
                            int pos = (int) l;
                            Receita rcta = (Receita) getItem(pos);
                            receitaDAO.deletar(rcta);
                            break;
                    }

                }

            });
            alert.show();
            return true;
        }
    });


    TextView data = (TextView)
            layout.findViewById(R.id.ddata);
    data.setText(lista.get(position).getData());

    TextView desc = (TextView)
            layout.findViewById(R.id.ddesc);
    desc.setText(lista.get(position).getDescricao());

    TextView valor = (TextView)
            layout.findViewById(R.id.vvalor);
    valor.setText(nf.format(lista.get(position).getValor()));

    return layout;


}
}
```

Método que salva a receita e volta pra lista

```
    public void salvarReceita(View view) {

    String[] data = etData.getText().toString().split("/");

    DateFormat dateFormat = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd");


    receita.setValor(Float.valueOf(etValor.getText().toString().substring(2, etValor.getText().toString().length()).replace(",", ".")));
    try {
        receita.setData((data[2] + "-" + data[1] + "-" + data[0]));
    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    receita.setDescricao(etDesc.getText().toString());

    ReceitaDAO receitaDAO = new ReceitaDAO(this);
    if (receita.getId() == 0)
        receitaDAO.inserir(receita);
    else
        receitaDAO.atualizar(receita);

    Toast.makeText(this, "Receita adicionada!", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();




    finish();


}
```

Comment: Quando você reabre a aplicação, as informações salvas, aparecem atualizadas?

Comment: @Lollipop reabro tipo, saio e entro no app? se for isso, sim, o app insere, edita, consulta e apaga, só não atualiza a listview automaticamente, tem que ficar saindo e voltando na list.

Comment: Saindo e voltando como? Saindo do app e voltando? OU DE UMA TELA PRA OUTRA(ou é isso que você queria?)?

Comment: Na verdade eu tenho a MainActivity, dela eu chamo a listview, eu preciso voltar pra main e clamar a lista pros dados virem atualizados, ou seja, ela só atualiza quando chama o onCreate(). @Lollipop

Comment: quando eu dou um finish() na tela de adição o app vai pra lista, e esta não vem atualizada, tem que voltar pra main e abrir a lista novamente pra lista vir atualizada. @Lollipop

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Se entendi bem o seu problema deve passar a chamada a `refreshLista();` para o metodo `onResume` da *Activity*:

```
public class ListReceitaActivity extends ActionBarActivity {

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_list_receita);

    //refreshLista();
}

@Override
public void onResume(){

    refreshLista();
    super.onResume();
}
```

Comment: Perfeito @ramaral, direto ao ponto, funcionou.

Answer (score 1):

O problema acontece porque quando você vai para a próxima atividade, `EditaReceitaActivity.class`, você não está destruindo a atividade anterior, que não é recomendado, caso não deseje consumir mais um tempo para recria-la. No entanto, o seu problema requer a destruição da atividade principal como uma das soluções. Seria algo como isto, no Oncreate da atividade `EditaReceitaActivity.class`:

```
Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP
```

**Sobre** FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP:

http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/Intent.html#FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP

---

A outra opção seria utilizar o onResume(), pois quando você volta, estará "resumindo a atividade principal E NÃO recriando, como você pensou":

```
@Override
protected void onResume(){

refreshLista();
super.onResume();
}
```

**Sobre** onResume():

http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Activity.html#onResume()

Comment: Agradeço a resposta, o Android trabalha o conceito de pilha, não estava me ligando nisso.

Comment: De nada, brother!